# How can I create a "wireframe" texture for a sphere in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, sphere, swift, scenekit

I've been struggling to figure this out. I would like to have a sphere in SceneKit that looks like this:

[image: Wireframe sphere]

I think the easiest way would be to create a mostly transparent texture with the wireframe lines. I need some help figuring out how to create this texture.

I've been doing some trial and error with colored lines to try to figure this out, but it's a mess and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Eventually I want to procedurally generate the wireframe texture in a `CALayer`, but first I need to figure out where to draw the lines.

Comment: Can't SceneKit just draw... a wireframe sphere?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Have you seen [this question + solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020674/scenekit-how-to-draw-a-sphere-showing-mesh-like-surface-instead-of-smooth)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's not going to work for me. The first reason is that I'm using Metal instead of OpenGL. And the other reason is that calling `glPolygonMode` changes the lines for ALL objects in the scene, but I need more fine-grained control.

Comment: You can use `glPolygonMode` and just turn it back off before the next object.

Comment: @MickLH - Nope, unfortunately you can't turn it on and off for different objects. Secondly, I don't want to use OpenGL, it's slower than Apple's Metal renderer.

Comment: @nathan.f77 `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine` may also be useful to you.

Comment: Even if you for some reason decide you can't do the correct thing, you still don't want to waste the memory storing a texture that provides terrible pixelated image quality. You can use a shader to discard most of the surface during rendering, and avoid memory consumption and bandwidth stress.

Comment: Thanks, I've also already considered `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine`, and it also doesn't work because you can't control the width of the line. Nor can you control other things such as adding a gaussian blur if you wanted a neon glow, etc. etc. Trust me, I've been researching this for about a week now, and a texture is the right way to go. It won't be pixelated if it's the right size. And it also won't use that much memory.

Comment: I would, however, love to see a solution that iterates over geometry sources and elements and converts them to use `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine`. I've also spent a few hours trying to figure that out, but it's another thing that I couldn't get to work. Apparently it's more complex than simply changing the primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution didn't turn out quite as well as I'd like, but I'll post it up regardless as it may help someone out. To get something that better matches your figure I believe you'll need to build your own `SCNGeometry` with probably a box for each line. This can be done, and there's several examples on building your own geometry around, but it is a fair bit of code.

Anyway, I was hoping a quick shader modifier would get what you were after.

```
    let sm =
    "float u = _surface.diffuseTexcoord.x; \n" +
    "float v = _surface.diffuseTexcoord.y; \n" +
    "int u100 = int(u * 100.0); \n" +
    "int v100 = int(v * 100.0); \n" +
    "if (u100 % 10 == 1 || v100 % 10 == 1) { \n" +
    "    // do nothing \n" +
    "} else { \n" +
    "    discard_fragment(); \n" +
    "} \n"

    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    sphere.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface:sm]
    sphere.firstMaterial?.doubleSided = true
```

It uses the texture coordinates to calculate which fragments should be drawn, and which should be discarded.

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! I think this looks like the way to go, and Ill try to just reduce the segments to get more straight lines.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the material `fillMode` to `.lines`:

```
sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
```